# 12.10 64-bit install freezes on Asus UX32VD

Tags: boot-failure, 12.10, asus

I have been struggling to install Ubuntu on my shiny new Asus UX32VD (Zenbook) for a while. There were the usual set of problems with 12.04 (suspend/resume, some keys not working, right mouse pad key not working) so I switched to 12.10 beta. Suspend/resume never worked with 12.10 either and nomodeset option needed to be specified for the boot loader but I waited patiently for the final release and updated the 12.10 beta daily.

Around October 8, after an update the beta could not boot anymore, it froze at the Ubuntu title page (after all the 4 white dots turned to red). I continued updating the packages daily from the command prompt but I never managed to get the graphical environment to run again. I decided to wait for the release, thinking that I might have run into a beta release update problem.

Then yesterday the 12.10 release arrived and I am sad to declare that the release does exactly the same thing, booting from the CD. If I choose Try Ubuntu at boot time and specify nomodeset for the boot loader, the boot progresses until the Ubuntu logo/four red dots then freezes. Without nomodeset the screen stays black and nothing is displayed during boot.

Any idea, how to get Ubuntu running on Asus UX32VD? It has a Windows7 installation and that works fine.

Comment: i think you better to file a bug .

Comment: I checked the bug reporting procedure but I cannot really run any tool at the point of freeze. Virtual consoles don't work either. I never reported an Ubuntu bug before.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

sorry .. i am french , but ...

the final 12.10 version of ubuntu work quiet well on asus ux 32vd for me, double boot with win 7 pro.

I used the amd 64 version , booting from a cd . Probably because of using the esc touch at the beginning, i suppose the cd start on uefi mode: a black screen with a line like " grub loader  ..." then the live session begin normally. (Previously i did 4 partition after reducing the "data" partition of win : / 20 go ; swap 4,5 go ; home 4 go ; "reserve boot " 500 mo. ). I click on the icon "install" after connecting wifi; and choose the personnalise option for that the installation use my 4 partition.

When the install was finish , the reboot was correct , grub had ubuntu and win, but win 7 didn't be able to start : message like " unable to locate valid efi file ". But ubuntu start with no problem.

I just have to load boot repair and use it. At the end there was an advertisement like " may be you should have to add an entry in the bios ...". but ...

I restart and grub had 2 line more : win loader efi , win repair efi ( approximately) ; and this work with no problem.  So it's great.

What works ? Keys for chicklet led ; wifi ; sound ; and evrything with good velocity.

Problems ? keys for adjust screen light ; unable ( for the moment to read a recent dvd even with VLC; and may be the length of battery seems short .

These are only first impression , I didn't have time to solve thes "small" problems ( I hope ! ) but anyway , thanks to canonical for this work , essentially to arrive to install the dual boot wheter the uefi bios.

Hope this will be useful for you. Malain

Comment: add on : I load boot-repair since ubuntu in the "logithéque" because ubuntu start with no problem. Malain

Comment: add on 2 : precision : when you start the pc, press "esc" ; a popup menu appears, and you can choose to boot on " dvd efi "; which is necessary to install on a pc with efi bios. Malain